# Top down movement/isometric movement in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm sorry if this question has already been asked before but I've checked everywhere and I can't find the answer.

How do you do top down movement in pygame?

This would be easy if I was just using rectangles but I'm going to be using individual character sprites (Ex. If I press d to make player go right, it shows me the character sprite of him going right and moves the character right).

Example image of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You draw a different sprite depending on which direction the character is going.

Assuming `dx` / `dy` are the character's velocity and `x`/`y` its location on screen,

```
up_sprite = pygame.image.load('up.png')
down_sprite = pygame.image.load('down.png')
left_sprite = pygame.image.load('left.png')
right_sprite = pygame.image.load('right.png')

sprite = down_sprite  # to initialize things off with

def your_game_loop():

    if dx > 0:
       sprite = right_sprite
    elif dx < 0:
       sprite = left_sprite
    elif dy > 0:
       sprite = down_sprite
    elif dy < 0:
       sprite = up_sprite

    sprite.blit(screen, (x, y))
```

Comment: What should I use for the pygame_draw_call_here function?

Comment: @rahsut I replaced the calls with more real ones.

Comment: I did it but nothing is showing on the screen. The sprite isn't showing up on the screen and for some reason, every time I close the game, I get the error "pygame.error: display Surface quit".

Comment: Ask another question with your actual current code and someone might be able to help.